# The soundtrack to my life; track four

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music, acrostic

I'm looking for a song, but I can't remember the words. I partially remember the lyrics to a few songs that played around it on my mixtape growing up, but that's about it. Can you help me?

> Gardens, new cars, and a house up in the hills.
> Oh May, do you want to get married, or run away?
> Now I'll get over you, I know my ship's not sinking.
>
> Six pennies leave me none the richer.

What song am I looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say your difficult-to-remember song is most likely:

> **[Kiss Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_Me_(Sixpence_None_the_Richer_song))**, released in 1997 by [Sixpence None the Richer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixpence_None_the_Richer) *([Listen on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N-qO3sPMjc))*

Based primarily on:

> (i) the first letters of each line spelling 'SNOG' (a synonym for 'kiss') in reverse;
>  (ii) the final line referring to the band's name.

Words similar to the partial lyrics listed are found in the following songs also released in the 1990's:

*Gardens, new cars, and a house up in the hills.*

> *[I Will Buy You a New Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Will_Buy_You_a_New_Life)*, by Everclear (1997):
>
>  *I will buy you a garden*
>  *Where your flowers can bloom*
>  *I will buy you a new car*
>  *Perfect shiny and new*
>  *I will buy you that big house*
>  *Way up in the West Hills*

*Oh May, do you want to get married, or run away?*

> *[Slide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_(Goo_Goo_Dolls_song))*, by Goo Goo Dolls (1998):
>
>  *Oh, May*
>  *Put your arms around me*
>  *What you feel is what you are*
>  *And what you are is beautiful*
>  *Oh, May*
>  *Do you wanna get married?*
>  *Or run away?*

*Now I'll get over you, I know my ship's not sinking.*

> *[King of Wishful Thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_Wishful_Thinking)*, by Go West (1990):
>
>  *I'll get over you I know I will*
>  *I'll pretend my ship's not sinking*

Potentially of note is that:

> The *titles of these songs* begin with the letters of 'KISS' (albeit with only one 'S'), which may be another nod towards this particular song.
>
>  <sup>(Alternatively - and yes, this is a joke -  there may be a further acrostic at play here using the *band names*; in which case, to quote a [movie from 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Runnings) (the same era as this puzzle): [*I'm not kissing no **EGG**.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKer-UG5EJY))</sup>

Comment: There is a second acrostic at play based on song title, but it's only partial (missing a single letter) and was intended as a hint. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Aha, I did actually spot that and wondered if I was missing an 'S' somehow! I chose not to include it because of that, but I'll mention it above...